# Lubuntu LXDE issues with Gis weather running in compton

Tags: conky, compton

I've done a lot of google searching on this and can only assume that I'm not setting my compton.conf just right. I have shadows and a blurry background on my Gis Weather where it should be a transparent one. I've looked in my Gis Weather config file to see if I could set it like I did my conky with own_window-type to desktop but, I can't find that line anywhere in the config file. I also have tried my hand at setting the compton.conf file but I'm having no luck. I have only been messing around with conky and compton for a few weeks now, so I'm not real sure about what I'm doing just yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my compton.conf file.

```
shadow = true;
no-dnd-shadow = true;
no-dock-shadow = true;
clear-shadow = true;
shadow-radius = 5;
shadow-offset-x = -4;
shadow-offset-y = -4;
shadow-opacity = 0.4;
shadow-red = 0.0;
shadow-green = 0.0;
shadow-blue = 0.0;
shadow-exclude = [ "name = 'Notification'", "class_g = 'Conky'", "class_g ?= 'Notify-osd'", "name *= 'Firefox'", "name *= 'VLC'", "name*='youtube'" ];
shadow-ignore-shaped = false;
menu-opacity = 0.75;
inactive-opacity = 0.75;
active-opacity = 1.0;
frame-opacity = 1.0;
inactive-opacity-override = false;
alpha-step = 0.15;
inactive-dim = 0.5;
blur-kern = "3x3box";
blur-background-exclude = [ "window_type = 'dock'", "window_type = 'desktop'" ];
fading = true;
fade-in-step = 0.03;
fade-out-step = 0.03;
fade-exclude = [ ];
backend = "glx";
mark-wmwin-focused = true;
mark-ovredir-focused = true;
detect-rounded-corners = true;
detect-client-opacity = true;
refresh-rate = 0;
vsync = "opengl-swc";
dbe = false;
paint-on-overlay = true;
focus-exclude = [ "class_g = 'Cairo-clock'" ];
detect-transient = true;
detect-client-leader = true;
invert-color-include = [ ];
glx-copy-from-front = false;
glx-swap-method = "undefined";
wintypes : 
{
  tooltip : 
  {
    fade = true;
    shadow = false;
    opacity = 0.75;
    focus = true;
  };
};
fade-delta = 20;
inactive-dim-fixed = false;
```

Comment: Post the compton file's content without the picture

Comment: Not sure how to do that. This is only my 2nd question I ever asked on here.